# Symfony date filter works on local but not on remote

Tags: symfony, heroku

A date filter seems to be the cause of a 500 Internal Server Error on remote with Heroku while it is working fine on local. Anyone would have an idea of why?

```
<small class="mt-3 text-muted"><span>{{ date|format_datetime('full', 'short',locale='fr') }}</span> [France, Paris]</small>
```

The php.ini file is set this way on local:

```
[Date]
date.timezone = Europe/Paris
```

Is there a setting I am missing?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [HTTP 500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_server_errors) is a generic server-side error message. On its own it doesn't tell us anything useful. Any time you see this your first step should be to check your error logs for more detail. On Heroku, you can do this by running [`heroku logs`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-logs).

Comment: @Chris I knew that! I just have to remember it :-) Thank you, I could solve the bug